# An Expedient Method to Force a TOC Entry onto the Following Page

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[showframe,paperwidth=4in,paperheight=3.5in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Chapter}
\addtocontents{toc}{Heading I}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section 1}
\addtocontents{toc}{\noindent Heading II}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section 1}
\end{document}
```

THE TOC:

[image]

[image]

Might there be a simple way, a command maybe, that will force the "Heading II" entry onto the next page in the TOC? I compile with `pdflatex`.

I know that I can add some vertical space that will do the job, but this situation comes up from time to time for me, and I would like to know if there is an expedient way of forcing a TOC entry onto the next page.

Comment: `\addtocontents{toc}{\clearpage}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried putting that immediately before the Heading II entry, but I get an error indicated "Tex capacity exceeded."

Comment: oh use `\protect\clearpage`

Comment: Try leaving blank lines between the `\add*contents*` lines.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\protect\clearpage`---That's the ticket! Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a page break via

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\clearpage}
```